# Where is 'links' defined?

Tags: ruby

I'm new at Ruby and trying to understand this code. I am wondering where 'links' (@links = {}) is defined in 'def initialize'. There is the function with the same name. Is the 'links' in 'def initialize' pointing the function? Then how could @links = {} work?

```
#---
# Excerpted from "Mazes for Programmers",
# published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
# Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
# courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
# We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
# Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/jbmaze for more book information.
#---
require 'distances'

class Cell
  attr_reader :row, :column
  attr_accessor :north, :south, :east, :west

  def initialize(row, column)
    @row, @column = row, column
    @links = {}
  end

  def link(cell, bidi=true)
    @links[cell] = true
    cell.link(self, false) if bidi
    self
  end

  def unlink(cell, bidi=true)
    @links.delete(cell)
    cell.unlink(self, false) if bidi
    self
  end

  def links
    @links.keys
  end

  def linked?(cell)
    @links.key?(cell)
  end

  def neighbors
    list = []
    list << north if north
    list << south if south
    list << east  if east
    list << west  if west
    list
  end

  def distances
    distances = Distances.new(self) 
    frontier = [ self ]

    while frontier.any? 
      new_frontier = [] 

      frontier.each do |cell| 
        cell.links.each do |linked| 
          next if distances[linked] 
          distances[linked] = distances[cell] + 1 
          new_frontier << linked 
        end
      end

      frontier = new_frontier 
    end

    distances
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@links = {}` is an instance variable and is available to all methods within the class. which you can later access in the links method. While having the same name one is object and one is a method.

Comment: Thank you Petros. so if I understand correctly, we don't need to declare a variable in the class prior to use it in Ruby? Anytime we need a member variable, we can just do like @variable = 0?

Comment: Correct, @CodingBadly ;)

Comment: Thank you for the confirm! @Ursus